# string not populating with array data, even though arrays are not really empty

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa

I am trying to create a non-Document-based application for Mac OS X that randomizes cards for the game of Dominion.

From many of the ones I have tried, the only thing I cannot seem to do is limit the number of sets picked from a selection made by the user, and things worked pretty well in my program, but I am having issues.

I am trying to get the results to print in a custom view, but every time I look at the print preview, nothing shows, except header text, as specified in an NSMutableString.

This piece of code is what is being used to print and is found in MasterViewController:

```
- (IBAction)print:(id)sender
{
   NSMutableString *content = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Cards\r\n\r\n"];

   for (int i = 0; i < [supply.game count]; i++)
   {
      [content appendFormat:@"Card: %@ Set: %@ Cost: %d\r\n", [supply.game[i] name], [supply.game[i] collection], [supply.game[i] cost]];
  }

  [content appendFormat:@"\r\n\r\nRequired\r\n\r\n"];

  for (int i = 0; i < [[setup supply] count]; i++)
  {
     NSDictionary* current = [setup supply][i];
     NSString* key = [current allKeys][0]; // get the key of the current dictionary must be 0, as there is only one key
     int value = [[current valueForKey:key] integerValue]; // variable to hold key value

     if (value > 0) {
         [content appendFormat:@"%@: %@", key, @"Yes"];
     }
     else
     {
         [content appendFormat:@"%@: %@", key, @"No"];
     }
   }

   printView.content = [NSMutableString stringWithString:content];
   [printView print:sender];
}
```

the data initially gets filled into some tableviews, which displays the correct content, and the supply.game array is the exact array that contains cards used for games.

setup is a property that refers to a view controller that populates a table with kinds of cards that may be required for games (e.g. shelters, colonies, ruins, spoils, and potions) and the supply method is supposed to return the array that view controller creates, which is itself not empty, as that table populates properly.

printView is a property that is assigned to a custom view found in MainMenu.xib and is the real view being used to print from.

the printView class looks like this:

header:

```
 #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

 @interface PrintView : NSView
 {
    NSMutableString* content;
 }

 @property NSMutableString* content;

 - (void)drawStringInRect:(NSRect)rect; // method to draw string to page
 - (void)print:(id)sender; // method to print
@end
```

implementation:

```
 #import "PrintView.h"

 @implementation PrintView
 @synthesize content;

 - (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
 {
    return YES;
 }

 - (void)print:(id)sender
{
    [[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:self] runOperation];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
   NSGraphicsContext *context = [NSGraphicsContext currentContext];

   if ([context isDrawingToScreen])
   {
   }

   else
   {
      [[NSColor whiteColor] set];
      NSRect bounds = [self bounds];

      if (content == nil || [content length] == 0)
      {
          NSRectFill(bounds);
      }
      else
      {
           [self drawStringInRect:bounds];
      }
   }
}

- (void)drawStringInRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSSize strSize; // variable to hold string size
    NSPoint strOrigin; // variable used to position text
    NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [attributes setObject:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
    [attributes setObject:[NSColor blackColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];

    strSize = [content sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
    strOrigin.x = rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width - strSize.width)/2;
    strOrigin.y = rect.origin.y + (rect.size.height - strSize.height)/2;
    [content drawAtPoint:strOrigin withAttributes:attributes];
}

@end
```

When I check the array sizes for printing operation, the size of the arrays is reported as zero, thus resulting in my current problem

If you need more code, here is code from [Github](https://github.com/bryceac/Raminion/tree/master/Raminion), but I do not have the experimental branch up there, which is where the above code came from, though it should not be too different.

The MasterViewController will show how the supply.game array is made and SetupViewController houses the code that is used to determine what is needed in the game, as well as show how the supply array from [setup supply] is being produced.

MasterViewController has also been added as an object to MainMenu.xib, so I do not know if that affects anything.

Any idea of what I need to do?

**Edit:** Added in info that might be relevant

Comment: What is the variable name of the array that you are talking about?

Comment: There are two arrays to deal with actually. game is a property of the Game class and the supply in supply.game array is an object of that class. In the case of [setup supply], variable that is called by the supply method is a variable called supply. They both are reported to be zero elements in size, even though tables are filled.